# text-align: center not centering anchor tags

Tags: html, css, anchor, centering, text-align

I want to center my anchor tag within its div.

Here is the html file:

```
<div class="body_div">
  <div class="verticle_center">

    <div id="links">
      ...
      <div id="linkedin" class="fill">
        <a href="#">linkedin</a>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css.scss:

```
.body_div {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .verticle_center{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
   #linkedin {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(26, 132, 188, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(26, 132, 188, 1);
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px 7px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: none;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:         0.19s ease-in;
    -o-transition:      0.19s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:     0.19s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:    0.19s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: 0.19s ease-in;
  }

}
```

But as seen here, within the blue highlighted area there is space to the right and I want it to be centered.
[image]

**Why is the `text-align: center;` within the `#linkedin{}` not centering the anchor tag and how do I achieve this effect?**

I have tried to add another `<div class="center">` and separately `<p>` around the anchor tags and within the anchor tags with no success. The image (for all these trials) ended up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there IS a space next to LinkedIn. Can you verify that there is no space.

Comment: @j08691 I have removed the embedded ruby code and replaced it with the rendered HTML.

Comment: @NawedKhan There is no space beside Linkedin. If you take a look at all the other links (Portfolio, Github and Blog) you will see that they are also not centered and seem to be aligned to the left.

Comment: can you make a fiddle please?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stecd/BvcP7/). I believe the solution below has solved it despite there still being a minor space beside the `n` from linkedin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you apply `display:inline` to your `#linkedin` div, you are telling it to override the normal `display:block` behavior for a div and basically turning it into a span. The container for inline elements shrinks to fit the element so centering won't work.

If you want the links side-by-side and centered in their container, use `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Great suggestion! This solution almost works but there is still (a very minimal) space to the right of each link. [view here](http://imgur.com/OYB1TUB).

Comment: `display:inline-block` should collapse whitespace between elements. Most likely you have margins set on the links. For `#linkedin` you have a 7px margin on the left and right.

Comment: The `display:inline-block` has collapsed the whitespace. Still, as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stecd/BvcP7/), there is a minor space beside the 'N'. Removing the margins didn't make a difference to that white space. I even came to believe the issue could be with the font, but even after changing the font, that little space after the link continues there. I'm very meticulous with my centering, but I'm not sure if this is a css/html problem anymore.

Comment: Your fiddle still has a margin of 7px attached. Also, just checking to make sure you aren't actually talking about the padding between the end of the letter and the end of the line? Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BvcP7/1/

Comment: Despite you having removed the right and left margin and padding, there still seems to be an uncounted for space at the end of the word. I made a [diagram](http://imgur.com/DfRwXAj) to illustrate this space.

Comment: You must be a web designer :P  2px of it are probably from the `letter-spacing:2px`, but I don't know why there is the extra 4px on the right side. I guess you could try a different font to see if it changes anything. Does the behavior occur in all browsers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55596/discussion-between-stecd-and-sam).